# como sumarle un porcentaje a un puntaje x

Tags: java

> Necesito sumarle el 20% a un puntaje x, soy nuevo en esto (tambien sumar el 30%,40% y 10%) nose si voy bien agradezco si me explica.

```
import ucn.StdOut;

import ucn.StdIn;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdOut.println("Ingrese puntaje:");
        double puntaje=StdIn.readDouble();
        StdOut.println("Ingrese zona de alianza:");
        String zona=StdIn.readString();
        StdOut.println("Ingrese color de alianza:");
        String color=StdIn.readString();
        double sumPorcentaje=puntaje;
        if (zona.equals("A") && color.equals("Rojo")){
            double puntajeTotal=sumPorcentaje+puntaje;
            StdOut.println("Su bonificacion es de 20%");
            StdOut.println("Su puntaje es:"+sumPorcentaje);
            sumPorcentaje=puntaje*0.2;
        }
        else{
            if (zona.equals("B")&& color.equals("Amarillo")){
                StdOut.println("Su bonificacion es de 30%");
            }
            else{
                if(zona.equals("A")&& color.equals("Azul")){
                    StdOut.println("Su bonificacion es de 40%");
                }
                else{
                    StdOut.println("Su bonificacion es de 10%");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Para sacar el 101% o superior de cualquier numero haces lo siguiente.

Para este ejemplo usaré el valor 100 (por fines prácticos)

Sumar el 5% al valor sería **cantidad** x 1.**05**, entonces, **100** x 1.05 = 105

Sumar el 10% al valor sería **cantidad** x 1.**10**, entonces, **100** x 1.10 = 110

Sumar el 20% al valor sería **cantidad** x 1.**20**, entonces, **100** x 1.20 = 120

Sumar el 70% al valor sería **cantidad** x 1.**70**, entonces, **100** x 1.70 = 170